# python pandas: rename single column label in multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, rename, dataframe, multi-index

I have a df that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,4)))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['1','2'],['A','B']])
print df
          1                   2          
          A         B         A         B
0  0.030626  0.494912  0.364742  0.320088
1  0.178368  0.857469  0.628677  0.705226
2  0.886296  0.833130  0.495135  0.246427
3  0.391352  0.128498  0.162211  0.011254
```

How can I rename column '1' and '2' as 'One' and 'Two'?

I thought df.rename() would've helped but it doesn't. Have no idea how to do this?

Comment: In newer versions of pandas, `df.rename()` can be used to rename particular levels. See [kadee's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50348947/3388962) answer below.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That is indeed something missing in `rename` (ideally it should let you specify the level).
Another way is by setting the levels of the columns index, but then you need to know all values for that level:

```
In [41]: df.columns.levels[0]
Out[41]: Index([u'1', u'2'], dtype='object')

In [43]: df.columns = df.columns.set_levels(['one', 'two'], level=0)

In [44]: df
Out[44]:
        one                 two
          A         B         A         B
0  0.899686  0.466577  0.867268  0.064329
1  0.162480  0.455039  0.736870  0.759595
2  0.620960  0.922119  0.060141  0.669997
3  0.871107  0.043799  0.080080  0.577421

In [45]: df.columns.levels[0]
Out[45]: Index([u'one', u'two'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 10):

As of pandas 0.22.0 (and probably much earlier), you can specify the level:

`df = df.rename(columns={'1': one, '2': two}, level=0)`

or, alternatively (new notation since pandas 0.21.0):

`df = df.rename({'1': one, '2': two}, axis='columns', level=0)`

But actually, it works even when omitting the level:

`df = df.rename(columns={'1': one, '2': two})`

In that case, all column levels are checked for occurrences to be renamed.

Answer (score 5):

Use `set_levels`:

```
>>> df.columns.set_levels(['one','two'], 0, inplace=True)
>>> print(df)
        one                 two          
          A         B         A         B
0  0.731851  0.489611  0.636441  0.774818
1  0.996034  0.298914  0.377097  0.404644
2  0.217106  0.808459  0.588594  0.009408
3  0.851270  0.799914  0.328863  0.009914
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 4):

```
df.columns.set_levels(['one', 'two'], level=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 4):

`df.rename_axis({'1':'one', '2':'two'}, axis='columns', inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. Combining the answer above, you can write a function:

```
def rename_col( df, columns, level = 0 ):

    def rename_apply ( x, rename_dict ):
        try:
            return rename_dict[x]
        except KeyError:
            return x

    if  isinstance(df.columns, pd.core.index.MultiIndex):
        df.columns = df.columns.set_levels([rename_apply(x, rename_dict = columns ) for x in df.columns.levels[level]], level= level)
    else:
        df.columns =                       [rename_apply(x, rename_dict = columns ) for x in df.columns              ] 

    return df
```

It worked for me.

Ideally, a functionality like this should be integrated into the "official" "rename" function in the future, so you don't need to write a hack like this.